# how to output a variable on turtle screen?

Tags: python, python-turtle

**I am trying to output a variable with text in turtle but it always outputs the wrong thing
im trying to write "point 1 (100, 100) where x1 = 100, y1 = 100**

```
#writing the text
turtle.goto(point1)
turtle.write("point 1 (",x1",",y1,")")
```

Comment: What does it print instead?

Comment: well it says turtle.write takes only 4 arguements instead of 5, but when i put what i want to print inside a sting and then print it, it prints: ("point 1(", 100, ",", 100, ")")

Answer (score 1):

You manipulated the quotation marks a bit wrongly. Try using [`f-strings`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/):

```
turtle.write(f"point 1 ({x1}, {y1})")
```